# Unable to register channel (IRC)

Tags: irc, chat

I created and register my nickname yesterday using this guide - https://freenode.net/kb/answer/registration

```
/nick YourNick
```

```
/msg NickServ REGISTER YourPassword youremail@example.com
```

then adding a alternate nick

```
/nick YourNick2
```

```
/msg NickServ IDENTIFY YourNick YourPassword
```

```
/msg NickServ GROUP
```

then I received an email

```
/msg NickServ VERIFY REGISTER apoorv569 (some random letter)
```

then I logged in by

```
/connect chat.freenode.net 6667 YourNick:YourPassword
```

I successfully created my user and registered it. But I'm not able to register my channel or become an channel operator

whenever I try to register my channel according to this guide - https://wiki.rizon.net/index.php?title=Channel_Registration

```
/msg ChanServ REGISTER #channel password description
```

I get an error saying `You must be a channel operator in #apoorv569 in order to register it.`

and whenever I try to become a channel operator according to this guide - http://data.agaric.com/how-become-channel-operator

```
/msg chanserv op #channel YourNick
```

I get this error `Channel #apoorv569 is not registered.`

I'm stuck in this loop, what should I do?

Comment: Join the channel. Maybe try to get to know IRC first. // This question is about using an internet-accessible service and as such off-topic here.

Comment: I had this post on stack overflow, 3 people told me to move this post here on superuser.
And I tried all of the above after joining the channel only.

Comment: There is no appropriate site on the Stack Exchange network for this question. // When you join a _new_ channel, you automatically get `+o`. // Freenode is sure to have a support channel. I suggest you use it.

Answer (score 2):

> whenever I try to register my channel according to this guide

That's the wrong guide.

Different IRC networks use different software for their IRC services. Freenode uses the Atheme services package, but the instructions you found on Rizon's website are for Anope 1.8 (or something similar).

For example, there is no such thing as a "channel registration password" in Atheme – instead the channel registration is simply tied to your NickServ account.

> I'm stuck in this loop, what should I do?

If the channel has someone else with channel operator privileges, ask them to op you as well (using the `/mode +o name` command).

If the channel has a few people but none of them are chanops, ask them all nicely to leave.
When you're the last person remaining in the channel, leave it and quickly rejoin (e.g. using the `/cycle` command) – the channel will be destroyed and re-created, giving you chanop privileges again.

If neither of the above is possible, then you cannot register the channel. Contact network staff or just move to a different channel.

Comment: There is no one in the channel, I'm trying to create my own channel, my Nick is apoorv569, and I'm using `irssi` as the IRC client. I have put my username and password in the `irssi` config file, so anytime I open `irssi` and type `/connect chat.freenode.net` it auto connects to username and password. after logging in I did `/join #apoorv569` and I successfuly joined my room, then according to your post I did `/mode +o apoorv569` I get `You're not a channel operator`. I tried doing`/cycle` as well no luck.

Comment: @apoorv569 Use   `/msg ChanServ OP #ChannelName NickName`   instead of   `/mode +o NickName`